# domain expire date query on other country servers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm working on an API that identifies websites whose domain ends with a domain query.

I do this with **WhoisClient.Query(domainName)**
I'm querying domains like .com and .tr successfully but I can't get a response in domains such as .de and .ba

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have you got same error when you try with IP address ? And could you please share your code and exception as well ?

Comment: It would be great if you could share your `code snippet` in addition, are you following any official guidelines for executing the query on `WhoisClient` or are you using any `Nuget package` for that? How you are trying that Please share more details on it.